# Show that every ideal in the ring of Gaussian integers is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, gaussian-integers

I'm doing Exercise 9 in textbook Algebra by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

[image]

> Show that every ideal in the ring of Gaussian integers is principal.

Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or contains logical mistakes? Thank you so much for your help!

---

Let

- $\mathbb Z[i]$ denote the ring of Gaussian integers.
- The norm $N(z) = z \overline{z}$ for $z \in \mathbb Z[i]$.
- $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Among all non-zero elements of $I$, we pick $a$ such that $N(a)$ is the smallest. For $b \in I$, by [Euclidean division algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814722/proof-of-euclidean-division-algorithm-for-the-ring-of-gaussian-integers), there are $r,s \in \mathbb Z[i]$ such that $b =ra+s$ and $N(s) \le N(a)/2$. By construction, $s=0$ and thus $I = \langle a \rangle$. This completes the proof.

Comment: I don't see where $N(s)\le N(a)/2$ came from, but certainly we have $N(s)<N(a)$. Other than that, looks good.

Comment: @ElliotG That's certainly the most essential argument in the proof. That's why I attach the link to the proof of Euclidean division algorithm in my previous thread :))

Comment: That's fine; I'm just saying you only need to use the fact that there is a Euclidean algorithm here. There is nothing to be gained from having $N(s)\le N(a)/2$ rather than $N(s)<N(a)$.

Comment: @ElliotG Just an attraction for a stronger result ^^

Comment: The proof is fine. More generally the argument shows that every Euclidean domain is a PID.