# Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z$ such that $cd\neq 0$. Then there exist $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $(a-cx+dy)^2 + (b-cy-dx)^2 \le (c^2+d^2)/2$

Tags: inequality, integers

In proving the ring of Gaussian integers is a principal ideal domain, I boil down to

> **Theorem:** Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z$ such that $cd\neq 0$. Then there exist $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $$(a-cx+dy)^2 + (b-cy-dx)^2 \le (c^2+d^2)/2$$

I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814722/proof-of-euclidean-division-algorithm-for-the-ring-of-gaussian-integers). Because of heavy algebraic manipulation, I'm not fond of it.

I would like to ask for a cleaner way to prove this **theorem**. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Are you asking for a cleaner way to prove the inequality or that the ring of Gaussian integers is a PID?

Comment: @SebastianCor Yeah, to prove the inequality.

Comment: The comments in the link you posted already give a geometric approach to this inequality as it is derived from the norm of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are you looking for something different, is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: @SebastianCor I'm working in the direction given in that comment. The theorem is stated in a very simple way that I'm curious about other approaches too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you do Euclidean division in $\mathbb Z$ (e.g. $u$ divided by $v$, at least for $v>0$)? You divide the numbers *without remainder* ($u/v$), and then you *truncate* the quotient ($q=\lfloor u/v\rfloor$) and take the remainder ($r=u-vq$). The idea here is that the quotient $q$ is "close" to the real quotient $u/v$, so that the remainder $r$ is "small" (smaller than $v$ in "size"). Indeed, $|r|=|u-vq|=|v(u/v)-vq|=|v(u/v-q)|=|v||u/v-q|$ and, as long as $q$ is very close to $u/v$ (in our case, due to truncation, the difference is less than $1$), $|r|<|v|\cdot 1=|v|$.

**The same** idea can be used in $\mathbb Z[i]$. Take two numbers $u=a+ib$ and $v=c+id$ from $\mathbb Z[i]$, and:

- First divide them as you would divide *any* two complex numbers. You get something like $u/v=x_0+iy_0$, but $x_0, y_0$ may not be integers.
- Now, what complex number is in $\mathbb Z[i]$ and "close" to $x_0+iy_0$? If you imagine the whole complex plane to be divided into $1\times 1$ grid, $x_0+iy_0$ belongs to one of those squares, and you can pick one of the corners of the grid - in fact, the closest corner $q=x+iy, x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

With that choice, $|(x+iy)-(x_0+iy_0)|\le\sqrt{2}/2$. Now you can try to estimate the "size" of the remainder $r=u-vq$. You would get, just as in $\mathbb Z$, that $|r|=|v||u/v-q|$ and, as $|u/v-q|\le\sqrt{2}/2$, we have $|r|\le|v|\sqrt{2}/{2}$ - or, equivalently, $|r|^2\le|v|^2/2$.

Now remind yourself that $r=u-vq=(a+ib)-(c+id)(x+iy)=(a-cx+dy)+i(b-cy-dx)$ and you will reach your desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much for a very clear exposition!